# Can I put same engagement split two times at different time interval in same journey flow?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, bounce-management

Can I put two same engagement split in journey at different time interval (in salesforce marketing cloud).

Here is the use case, I want to send an email and check if particular email has bounced or not. Ideally one should wait upto 3 days & check if email has bounced or not. But in this case I want to to put two checks, one is after one hour of send and other is after 3 days of send. Based on email bounced or delivered I'll update email status in salesforce sales cloud against Lead or Account.

Can I use same engagement split at different time interval (first one is after one hour and second one is after 3 days) and accordingly update the Lead & Account object in sales cloud.

Idea is to get bounce or deliver status in sales cloud as soon as delivered or bounced response is received in marketing cloud.

Comment: Hi Ashish. I have provide multiple answers to your questions, and would appreciate if you marked them as accepted if they are of help to you.

Comment: @LukasLunow- Sorry, my bad. You're answer is definitely helpful. Have marked as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily select the same email in multiple engagement splits within the same journey. You have the **Message to monitor** dropdown, which selects the email which the engagement split takes into consideration, and then **Message metrics** where you in your case will select **Bounces**.

Even though you have already selected Message X in one engagement split, you can select same message in any other engagement split further down the journey.